# How To Make Multiple TextViews Show The Value Of An Edited SharedPreference Each Time In Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I Have Created A Function That Dynamically Makes A Textview And Assigns The Values Of Shared Preferences To It.Now I Want To Make A New TextView Each Time The User Enters Data In It

There are 5 Shared Preferences - Day , Medicine ,Time , HowMuch ,When

```
   val shrd = getSharedPreferences("Add$dayselected", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                val editor = shrd.edit()
                editor.putString("medicine", medicine)
                editor.putString("day", dayselected)
                editor.putString("whenSelected", whenselected)
                editor.putString("medicineSelected", medicineselected)
                editor.putString("time", timeselected)
                editor.apply()
                Toast.makeText(this@Add, "Saved To Internal Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

These Are The Preferences

```
        val pref = getSharedPreferences("AddFriday", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val dayA = pref?.getString("day", "NOT FOUND ").toString()
    val medicinea = pref?.getString("medicine", "NOT FOUND ").toString()
    val whenSel = pref?.getString("whenSelected", "NOT FOUND ").toString()
    val mediselec = pref?.getString("medicineSelected", "NOT FOUND ").toString()
    val time = pref?.getString("time", "NOT FOUND ").toString()
```

Now I Have Assigned The Value Of Each Preference To A TextView

If The User Enters New Data I Want The New Textview To Have The New Data And The Old To Remain The Same

Functions To add Textviews

```
 private fun add_view(data: String, id: Int): View {

    val text = TextView(applicationContext)
    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 229, 229))
    text.width = 100
    text.height = 50
    text.x = 21F
    text.y = 88F
    text.id = id
    text.text = data

    return text
}

    private fun add_row(dayA: String, medicinea: String, whenSel: String, mediselec: String, time: String) {
    val layout: ConstraintLayout? = fridaylayout
    val dayview = add_view(dayA, R.id.dayf)
    val medicineview = add_view(medicinea, R.id.medicinef)
    medicineview?.x = +100F
    val whenselview = add_view(whenSel, R.id.whenf)
    whenselview?.x = +200F
    val mediselview = add_view(mediselec, R.id.howmuchf)
    mediselview?.x = +300F
    val timeview = add_view(time, R.id.timef)
    timeview?.x = +400F
    layout?.addView(dayview)
    layout?.addView(medicineview)
    layout?.addView(whenselview)
    layout?.addView(mediselview)
    layout?.addView(timeview)

}
```

Thank You

Asad

Comment: what you should do I think is to link the edited text id to the shared preference. you need to show us the " putstring" values edit your question